# Time Subtraction Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe that is trying to calculate the difference in minutes between 2 times. The code I used is just this.

```
start_time = pd.to_timedelta(duplicate_df['StartTime'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()
end_time = pd.to_timedelta(duplicate_df['EndTime'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()
duplicate_df['DurationMins'] = end_time.sub(start_time).div(60)
```

However, I have come across the issue, where depending on the time, this count can be negative and give the difference "the other way". For example in the first column here which indicates that the person is sleeping, the time should be for only 15 minutes instead of -1425.

[image]

I'm not quite sure how to go about coding this but one of the ideas I have got is check which numbers in the column are negative and then add the equivalent of 1 day of "minutes to it" to get the right number. Is there any more efficient or more elegant way of doing this and if so how would I go about it?

I have written this code to get the column into a list and then add it to each element that is negative but I feel like there might be a better way of doing it.

```
duration = duplicate_df['DurationMins'].values.flatten()

for i in range(len(duration)):
    if duration[i] < 0:
        duration[i] += (24*60)
```

Comment: Modulo operator.  You should be able to say `(end_time - start_time) // 60 % 1440`

Comment: You can do `abs` on timedelta: `endtime.sub(start_time).abs().div(60)`?

Comment: Would this method just give me a positve number instead? So for the first value I would get 1425 minutes slept instead which isn't quite right since they have only slept for 15?

Comment: @TimRoberts What would the // do here? wouldn't it still return the same value due to 1425 MOD 1440 not being 0?

Comment: `end_time - start_time` is seconds.  I'm dividing by 60 to get minutes.  In case it's not clear, use by code in your `duplicate_df['DurationMins']` assignment.  You don't need to post-process things.

Comment: But in this case it would still be giving my the value of -1425 no? Instead of just 15 which is 00:00 - 23:45?

Comment: Quang Hoang's method is wrong.  It will just give you +1425.

Comment: To be exact: `duplicate_df['DurationMins'] = (end_time - start_time) // 60 % 1440`

Comment: Ahhhhhh yes I see now, that makes a lot of sense. I think that's cleared it up TY!

Answer (score 0):

```
import pandas as pd

x = [[ '23:45:00', '00:00:00', 0], ['01:00:00','02:00:00', 0] ]
duplicate_df = pd.DataFrame( x, columns = ['StartTime','EndTime','DurationMins'])

start_time = pd.to_timedelta(duplicate_df['StartTime'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()
end_time = pd.to_timedelta(duplicate_df['EndTime'].astype(str)).dt.total_seconds()
#duplicate_df['DurationMins'] = end_time.sub(start_time).div(60)
duplicate_df['DurationMins'] = (end_time - start_time) // 60 % 1440
print( duplicate_df )
```

Result:

```
  StartTime   EndTime  DurationMins
0  23:45:00  00:00:00          15.0
1  01:00:00  02:00:00          60.0
```